# How to get folder microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs

missing
`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll`

I am using VS2019 and trying to move and build an old VB.net project from TFS2015 that uses an obsolete function HtmlFilter.ConvertToPlainText in

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll`

However, I cannot find the folder `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0` on my new PC, which means I cannot build the project
(BC30451: Name 'HtmlFilter' is not declared) and
I have missed something that I should install.
How could I get this folder and the dlls to my new PC? Install VS 2015 to get TFS2015's dll?

Answer (score 0):

The Path `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0` references the version of Visual Studio/TFS.

VS 2019 has the version number 16. Does the assembly exists under `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\16.0`?

Comment: Yes, it has, but I don't want to change the Project file.
`
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
`
This is not an individual project, I don't want to change the path of the references. So the best way is to let this TFS2015 (14.0) folder appear on my new PC.

Comment: Then you need to install a VS2015 Edition.